# read was not declared error message

Tags: c++, c, linux, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I am cross compiling a package (`libqmi`).(With simple compiling it was fine.)

The problem came out when I tried to comply a c++ part.
I got the message that is

`"read is not declared"`.

I know it does not need to be included in case of C, but what about C++?

I tried to add the headers by hand: `fcntl.h` and `unistd.h` too, without any solution.
(the compiler found them and included, but the error message is still left)

Do you have any idea what the problem can be behind this?
I do not think the problem is wrong, as it is a realised and good with host compiler.

EDIT:
thanks the comments.
host: Linux, x86,
target: Linux, arm

unistd.h header does not solved the problem:
I also tried type alloc, maybe there is misalloc.
GobiQMICore.cpp: In member function 'virtual std::vector, std::basic_string > > cGobiQMICore::GetAvailableDevices()':
GobiQMICore.cpp:319:39: error: 'read' was not declared in this scope
GobiQMICore.cpp:334:21: error: 'close' was not declared in this scope

the code:

```
/*===========================================================================
METHOD:
   GetAvailableQDLPorts (Public Method)

DESCRIPTION:
   Return the set of available Gobi QDL ports

RETURN VALUE:
   std::vector <sDeviceID>
===========================================================================*/
std::vector <std::string> cGobiQDLCore::GetAvailableQDLPorts()
{
   std::vector <std::string> devices;

   std::string path = "/sys/bus/usb/devices/";

   std::vector <std::string> files;
   DepthSearch( path,
                2,
                "ttyUSB",
                files );

   int fileNum = files.size();
   for (int i = 0; i < fileNum; i++)
   {
      // Example "/sys/bus/usb/devices/8-1/8-1:1.1/ttyUSB0"
      std::string nodePath = files[i];

      int lastSlash = nodePath.find_last_of( "/" );

      // This is what we want to return if everything else matches
      std::string deviceNode = nodePath.substr( lastSlash + 1 );

      // Move down one directory to the interface level
      std::string curPath = nodePath.substr( 0, lastSlash );

      // Read bInterfaceNumber
      int handle = open( (curPath + "/bInterfaceNumber").c_str(), 
                         O_RDONLY );
      if (handle == -1)
      {
         continue;
      }

      char buff[4];
      memset( buff, 0, 4 );

      bool bFound = false;
      int ret = read( handle, buff, 2 );
      if (ret == 2)
      {
         // Interface 1 or 0
         ret = strncmp( buff, "01", 2 );
         if (ret == 0)
         {
            bFound = true;
         }
         ret = strncmp( buff, "00", 2 );
         if (ret == 0)
         {
            bFound = true;
         }

      }
      close( handle );

      if (bFound == false)
      {
         continue;
      }

      // Move down one directory to the device level
      curPath = curPath.substr( 0, curPath.find_last_of( "/" ) );

      // Read idVendor
      handle = open( (curPath + "/idVendor").c_str(), O_RDONLY );
      if (handle == -1)
      {
         continue;
      }
      bFound = false;
      ret = read( handle, buff, 4 );
      if (ret == 4)
      {
         ret = strncmp( buff, "05c6", 4 );
         if (ret == 0)
         {
            bFound = true;
         }
      }
      close( handle );

      if (bFound == false)
      {
         continue;
      }

      // Read idProduct
      handle = open( (curPath + "/idProduct").c_str(), O_RDONLY );
      if (handle == -1)
      {
         continue;
      }
      bFound = false;
      ret = read( handle, buff, 4 );
      if (ret == 4)
      {
         ret = strncmp( buff, "920c", 4 );
         if (ret == 0)
         {
            bFound = true;
         }
      }
      close( handle );

      if (bFound == false)
      {
         continue;
      }

      // Success!
      devices.push_back( deviceNode );
   }

   return devices;
}
```

T

Comment: What's your target in the cross-compile? I'm assuming Linux is the host?

Comment: Your problem should be solved with inclusion of `unistd.h`.As you are saying you included already so just make sure that you included this for required and correct `c` file.

Comment: Show some code with this `read()` in it!

Comment: I just modified the question, adding some additional info, according to your comments. thanks

Comment: The code you've shown us has no `#include` directives, so it should give you errors for `read` as well as for `std::`, `DepthSearch`, and so forth. You say you have `#include <unistd.h>` in your code. *Show us that code*. Showing us something similar to your real code is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

> I know it does not need to be included in case of C, but what about C++?

I think that you should **always** include the headers you need. I guess your compiler is doing the job for you, if you use the "-Wall" parameter with gcc, you should get a warning.

Under Linux, to know what header you need to include just type `man function`. Sometime you might get the bash man page, for open you need to indicate the section `man 2 read` and in the synopsis, you have the required headers. To get those man pages, you also need to install the manpages-dev on Debian based distribution.

To answer to your question, I also had that kind of issue when I was writing C++ programs using a namespace. If you are inside a namespace, try calling this function like that `::read(...)`

Comment: thanks the comment
yes, I also thought that. but it is really interesting me why I do not get any error if I use my host compiler. I simple type ./configure 
and make without any parameter and there is no error. and in case of cross compiler I get the above stuffs.
I am afraid to manipulate the code can lead us to bad behaver later (it is a third party code and I have no time to understand so much I could refact) or the other thing probably there is serious configuration mistake which can cause other problem later.